# Android Studio XML Widgets not rendering properly in designer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

Recently, while working on some projects, I've had a rather annoying problem when coding the user interface of my application. The problem is, some controls (usually a floating action button or a regular button) render strangely. It's hard for me to explain exactly *how* it looks - but here's an example of how it shows the floating action button to look like in the designer:

[image]

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Now, the thing is, I don't have any weird or special code added, the XML code is as pure as it gets, so I have no idea why I am having these strange rendering problems.

Here is how it rendered the following button:

Code:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Submit"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:textAllCaps="false"
      android:layout_margin="30dp"
      app:cornerRadius="30dp"
      android:id="@+id/submitButton"
      android:backgroundTint="@color/turquoise"
      />
```

Image:

[image]

A solution would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Tom

Comment: Try to reload the designer or update android studio.

Comment: @danialiranpour thank you for the reply - I tried both but ultimately failed. Nothing has changed.

Comment: I don't know, I had this problem before but I solved it this way. It's weird.

Comment: @danialiranpour if I don't get a solution I will bounty it tomorrow - this is bothering me

Comment: I've also been having this problem for a while now, nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: Change orientation in your design window to trigger new rendering process.@TomJoney

Comment: @androidLearner still doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is simple u just need to restart your **android rendering engine**. I provided Image for your context . In android studio top right corner above layout display there is **Toggle issue panel** click on that and u will see one box in the bottom showing rendering issue **restart rendering engine** and that will restart your android studio. and u good to go. try this solution and let me know your issue is solved or not.

**note:**  In my Image I already restarted so there is no option for restart rendering engine .but in yours's U may be find hope so.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5ERw.jpg)